# Find the Maclaurin series for $\cos(2x)$ using the series for $\sin(2x) $.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I know that 
$$\sin(2x)= 2x - \frac{8x^3}{3!} + \frac{32x^5}{5!} - \frac{128x^7}{7!} + \cdots $$
$$\sin(2x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n {2^{2n+1}x^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)!}$$
But I don't see how I can use that series to find the series for $\cos(2x)$?
Is there any way I can use the Trig Identity $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin(x)^2$ ?

Comment: There's a simpler method. What's a primitive function of $\cos (2x)$?

Comment: Differentiate! or integrate and make sure your starting value is right.

Comment: Power series can be differentiated term-by-term in the interior of their intervals of convergence.  And in this case, the radius of convergence is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

For a positive $R$, this series expansion $$\sin(2x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n {2^{2n+1}x^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)!}$$ is valid for $x$ in $[-R, R]$. Differentiating term by term gives $$2\cos(2x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n {2^{2n+1}x^{2n} \over (2n)!},$$ valid for $x$ in $(-R, R)$. Hence this series expansion for $\cos(2x)$ is valid over the whole real line because $R$ was arbitrary.

Comment: $(\sin (2x))' = 2 \cos (2x)$